# Select and Decrease field value on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with mysql_query
I tried to find members who are online, there is a field "Online" in the members table are always updated with the time server. This is the query.

```
$ now = time ();
$ olline = mysql_num_rows (mysql_query ("select * from members where gender = 'Man' and (online - '$ now')> 10"));
```

in phpmyadmin there are 7 members in accordance with the above query. tp I get a value of 0. what is wrong with my code. tq for the answer and sorry for bad english

Comment: `'$ now'` -- what's this?

Comment: 1st of all, don't use mysql_* syntax. use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: Putting spaces between var names and $ and () will cause syntax errors

Comment: Your PHP syntax is incorrect, plus, you're using deprecated functions. Learn PHP first.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and always use Mysqli these days as before long Mysql will be gone completely. Mysqli example of your code:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$now = time(); // The time now for query calc
$gender = "Man"; // Gender for query

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); //Initialise statement
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE gender = ? AND (online - ?)> 10"); //Prepare the query
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $gender, $now); //Assign the query parameters
$stmt->execute(); // Execute the query
$stmt->store_result(); // store result of prepared statement
echo $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->free_result(); //free up the $stmt var
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable names cannot contain spaces, so your variable names are invalid. It should be `$now` or `$_now` and **NOT** `$ now`.  See [Language variable basics for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

**Correct code :**

```
    $now = time ();
    $olline = mysql_num_rows (mysql_query ("select * from members where gender = 'Man' and (online - '$now')> 10"));
```

Also , avoid using `mysql_` functions cause they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, I have clearly understood your question.

If I have understood correctly, you want to display the online available members.

Do you have any flag for checking if the member online or not?  If there is a flag then use that flag and filter by online status. This how we have to do for chat operations.

I am not sure, why you going with subtraction.